# Is there any technical reason to replace whitespaces by dashes on urls?

Tags: url, whitespace

I wanted to know if using dashes (or any other allowed character) is just because the whitespace encoding (%20) make urls less legible. I don't see any technical reason for this, but there might be something that I don't remember or don't know about.

Comment: Just wanted to throw in an example: [there-is-any-technical-reason-to-replace-whitespaces-by-dashes-on-urls](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9131354/there-is-any-technical-reason-to-replace-whitespaces-by-dashes-on-urls)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that it's primarily due to user preference.  As long as all the components handle the encoding properly, it should make no technical difference.

Here is an interesting writeup on it: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/04/of-spaces-underscores-and-dashes.html

His point about preferring a dash over an underscore is valid though, as most search engines treat a dash as a word-breaker, but an underscore is not so it's treated as a single word.  Therefore, that is a valid technical reason for a dash to be used instead of an underscore to replace spaces... but there's no technical requirement that I know of to use dashes over spaces in the URL itself.

Answer (score 1):

Dashes may already be used for something else, such as a filename with dashes so using them for a space could cause confusion, depending on how they're used.

`%20` is the hexadecimal equivalent of the ASCII character 32, which is a space.

SO uses dashes to make URLS "friendy" but it is not a requirement.

According to the [W3c Spec](http://www.w3.org/Addressing/URL/url-spec.txt):

> Spaces and control characters in URLs must be escaped for
>   transmission in    HTTP, as must other disallowed characters.